# Install Qt 4 ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, qt

I need to install Qt 4 in my computer to run a specific software. I've download Qt 4.8.6 from: https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.6/.
I followed the steps from the link http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/install-x11.html, but after I use `make` (step 3) I received the message:

> Makefile:1624: recipe for target 'obj/release/pcre_exec.o' failed
>   make[1]: *** [obj/release/pcre_exec.o] Error 1
>
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/qt/src/script'
>
>   Makefile:602: recipe for target 'sub-script-make_default-ordered' failed
>
>   make: *** [sub-script-make_default-ordered] Error 2

I've already tried this recomendations from the software (that I want to install after installed Qt4), and I stop at the same `make` command.

> Installation example (bash notation):
>
> VERS="4.x.y"             # Set Qt version number
>
> SRCDIR="${HOME}/src"     # Set path for source files
>   mkdir $SRCDIR
>   cd $SRCDIR
>   SRC="http://origin.releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source"
>   wget -N $SRC/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-$VERS.tar.gz
>   tar -xzvf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-$VERS.tar.gz
>   cd qt-everywhere-opensource-src-$VERS
>
> INSTDIR="/usr/local"
>
> PLATFORM="linux-g++-64"
>
> O1="-release -opensource -static"
>   O2="-qt-zlib -no-gif -qt-libpng -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg"
>   NO="-nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake docs -nomake translations"
>   ./configure $O1 $O2 $NO -prefix $INSTDIR/qt_$VERS -platform $PLATFORM
>                                # Confirm the license agreement

Someone knows how to proceed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Ubuntu 17.04 has it in repositories:

```
sudo apt install qt4-default
```

Comment: I did this, but it's very different than what is explained in Qt website and the tutorial for installation from the program that I need to install. I tryed to install the program after I did what you recommended, and it did not work.
In a log file the message that I received were:
`make: No specified targets and no files are found. Stop`

Comment: It's a rather old software. Just following the instructions may not always work on contemporary systems. Making it work need some experimentations and knowing what every command does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install qt creator(IDE) then just issue the following command

```
sudo apt install qt4-default
sudo apt install qtcreator
```